# How to detect source of Artifactory login attempts?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using Artifactory for everything: Docker images, NuGet packages, PyPi cache, you name it.  I don't have to pull things very often, but inevitably when I do, my account is locked.  I can request for it to be unlocked, and it will be, but then I turn around and it's locked again in no time.

Is there a way to determine where the logon attempts are coming from that are locking my account?  I've changed API Key and everything else...it just keeps happening. I've verified that my local machine has been fully updated with the new key, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned you rotated the Keys, I suspect some automation job/script/cron is trying to hit the Artifactory with wrong credentials.
Nevertheless, as a first point of check, validate artifactory-request.log files for any entries that could be coming from your API key

```
Example: 2021-10-19T01:13:52.523Z|3b65f083f8d51f74|**127.0.0.1**|**token:XXXXXX**|GET|/api/system/configuration/platform/baseUrl|200|-1|0|16|JFrog Event/7.12.4 (revision: 5060ba45bc, build date: 2020-12-26T18:54:28Z)
```

If the request is coming from an user the request would look like this:

```
2021-10-19T01:14:31.440Z|1de7b95f92082ff|**10.10.16.322**|**sssso2**|GET|/api/auth/screen/globalState|200|2|0|345|Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36
```

(note the IP and user above)
In addition to that you can grab the service id (1de7b95f92082ff is service id in the above example) and grep access-request.log file to get more information